# Probability of relations in a network

Tags: statistics, graph-theory

Imagine, i have a predicate $\text{friends}(x_1, x_2)$ and I know that $p(\text{friends}(x_1, x_2)) = p_2$. If I generate a world of $n$ people ($x_1$ to $x_n$), I expect there to be $\binom{n}{2}p_2$ friends. Now, imagine, I count the number of times that 3 people are all friends of each other in this world: $\binom{n}{3} p_3$. I expect the probability of three random people being friends to be $p_3$. ($p_2, p_3 \in [0..1]$)

I'm trying to calculate the probability that any 4 people in my world are all friends with each other. Without knowing $p_3$ I would estimate the probability to be $p_2^6$. But obviously knowing $p_3$ influences the probability. For example if $\frac{p_3}{p_2}$ increases, I expect the friendships to be denser and thus more 4 people will form groups. I have trouble however finding a formula to express this probability, because the probabilities that the different subgroups of 3 people are friends are not independent. And if I take four random people the probability that at least 3 subgroups of three people are friends is the same as that at least 4 subgroups of three people are friends.

Could you provide any advice on how one typically calculates such a problem or what to search for? By what factor does $\frac{p_3}{p_2}$ increase the probability of a third connecting edge in presence of two edges? I would assume one would somehow express this using conditional probabilities, although I can't seem to figure out exactly how.

Comment: Just a reformulation of the question, in case that helps.  Let $G$ be a random graph, each edge appearing with probability $p_2$.  Let $X \subset G$ with $|X| = 4$, and $A_X$ be the event that $X$ is a clique.  Calculating $Pr[A_x]$ is easy enough.  But now let $T_k$ be the event that $G$ has $k$ triangles.  Say someone counted the triangles and we're given $T_k$.  What is $Pr[A_X | T_k]$ ? I have no idea.  I always end up trying to find out what $Pr[T_k]$ is, which is out of my realm...